# Changing time into timestrings in PHP

Tags: php

On my website we store all time & date in the following format:

Table Column: Date - 16.01.2012
Table Column: Time - 06:36:50pm

This has been causing problems with those who live in different timezones, therefore we are looking at changing this to simple time() strings, however because theres a lot of content on our site that already has such time(old, not time() strings) in the database, we want to keep that data and therefore are wondering how we can go about changing those strings into time().

I understand how to update databases and all, I am lost on actually converting 16.01.201206:36:50pm into its respective time() string, as strtotime likes things to be perfect.

Thank you for your time, and I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Why didn't you use the default datetime format MySQL offers? That would have saved you all of this trouble.

Comment: @JohnConde Yes it would have, however I coded this panel a couple of years back, and have since just expanded onto it and now this is the only table that is using this format of dates, it is causing problems both backend and frontend and therefore is something I need to get fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to make the conversion in the database, or how to convert a datetime from the database when it gets loaded into your PHP?

If it's the latter, there are lots of ways that you can format your date.

Taken from the comments of the PHP manual for date_format:

```php
    <?php

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `datetime` FROM `table`");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $date = date_create($row[0]);

    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    #output: 2012-03-24 17:45:12

    echo date_format($date, 'd/m/Y H:i:s');
    #output: 24/03/2012 17:45:12

    echo date_format($date, 'd/m/y');
    #output: 24/03/12

    echo date_format($date, 'g:i A');
    #output: 5:45 PM

    echo date_format($date, 'G:ia');
    #output: 05:45pm

    echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
    #output: 5:45pm on Saturday 24th March 2012

    ?>
```

These are just some examples. Take a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) page for some more ideas.

**Edit based on comment:**

You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), which allows you to specify the format of the datetime that you are passing in.

Comment: Whilst helpful, I am trying to do neither. I already have the date format in my database as a Human Readable string, however I need to know how I can go about changing that into a php time() stamp.

Regards, and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No worries. My latest update should allow you to take your dates and times and convert them from any format that you specify.

Comment: Hello, I have a rough idea of how I can do this now then. I know that strtotime only likes American Formatted Dates, so I want to format my database times into the following format: **DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS** and then run them through strtotime, which will output the correct timestamp, correct?

Comment: Here's an example: $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y h:i:sa', '16.01.2012 06:36:50pm');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s a'); Since $date now contains a PHP date object, you are free to output it any way you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

look for `mysql` function called `str_to_date`

say you had dbtable text field called `date_str` and its format is YYYYMMDD. You can use the ff query to output a proper date field.

```
SELECT str_to_date(date_str, '%Y%m%D') as date_fld FROM dbtable ...
```

[here's the link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late, but I also think this should be done through the Database. I think this will remove a few extra steps, and maybe be a little faster than resorting to PHP's Date Formatting functions. You can write an SQL statement that looks like this:

```
"SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d.%m.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(Time, '%r'))) AS epoch FROM Table"
```

That should return everything in the proper time() format you're looking for.